# __doPostBack on Telerik RadGrid row drop

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I want to fire a event from java script doing `_doPostback`. This `_doPostBack` has to be called in radgrid on-row dropping client side function. The event I want to get fired is `OnRowDrop`. The code below doesn't work:

```
 __doPostBack('<%= rdgDriver.ClientID %>', 'OnRowDrop');
```

Comment: any one who knows a answer for this problem?

Comment: It seems like it isn't possible. From their own forum: https://www.telerik.com/forums/drop-into-unused-portion-of-grid#587045